# WPF closing child- closes parent-window

Tags: wpf, childwindow, mainwindow

i have the pretty same sample as mentioned [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tal_pasi/archive/2011/01/13/wpf-main-window-disappears-when-closing-the-last-owned-child-window.aspx). 
Fast concluded: MainWindow closes when the last childwindow is closed.

My Problem: I couldn't solve my problems with the described solutions. I can't produce a program where it als takes place. Only in one of my bigger progs. Maybe someone has an idea or knows any further steps.

Thanks for reading - Thomas

As requested here's a bit of code:
This is the part in the MainWindow:

```
bool editAfterSearch = false;
Movie selectedMovie = (Movie)this.listView.SelectedItem;
Movie backup = (Movie)selectedMovie.Clone();            

if (new OnlineSearchWindow().EditMovieViaOnlineSearch(ref selectedMovie, out editAfterSearch))
{
    this.coverFlow.Update(selectedMovie);
}
```

And that's the part of the ChildWindow:

```
public bool EditMovieViaOnlineSearch(ref Movie preset, out bool editAfter)
{
    this.exitWithOk = false;
    this.editMovieAfterSearch = false;

    this.tbx_SearchTerm.Text = preset.Title;
    this.linkedMovie = preset;

    this.ShowDialog();

    editAfter = editMovieAfterSearch;

    if (this.exitWithOk)
    {
        this.linkedMovie.CloneOnlineInformation(ref preset);
        preset.Bitmap = this.linkedMovie.Bitmap;

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please describe your design and what exactly you cannot do like it is mentioned in the blog post? I don't get it at the moment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try playing with the `ShutDownMode` property of your `App.xaml.cs`. The 3 values are `OnMainWindowClose`, `OnLastWindowClose`, and `OnExplicitShutdown`, and the default is `OnLastWindowClose`

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        this.ShutdownMode = System.Windows.ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Do you have an explanation for your solution?

Comment: Well the default `ShutdownMode` is `OnLastWindowClose`, so if you close all your child windows then it will close the application. `OnMainWindowClose` means the application will shutdown when your `App.Current.MainWindow` closes, and `OnExplicitShutdown` means it will only close when you tell it to close.

Comment: So does the MainWindow not count as window when OnLastWindowClose?

Comment: @ThomasSpranger I'm not sure, but it probably depends on if the `MainWindow` is shown or not.

Comment: Interesting thing. In my case it was visible all the time. Anyway - Thanks on more time!

Answer (score 1):

1. The below code worked for me.

```
 private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBoxResult.No == (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to close this?.", "ProjectName", MessageBoxButton.YesNo)))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                foreach (var item in Application.Current.Windows)
                {
                    Window window = item as Window;
                    if (window.Title == "PopUpWindowName")
                    {
                        window.Topmost = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnClosed(e);
                Application.Current.Shutdown();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try setting the child window's `allowShutDown` to `false` and then show the mainwindow. I'm assuming you will start with mainwindow's visibility set to `hidden`.

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
this.allowShutDown = false;
```

The `allowShutDown` will be your own property which u can set to enable you have to handle the `closing` event.